# Samsung Pie Background BLE Scan

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm currently having issues with Samsung Devices running Android Pie.
My App is using a foreground service with an active notification. Once a geofence is entered I'm scanning for a bluetooth beacon.
This works on all devices across all Android versions (also used to work on Samsung devices running oreo).

The problem begins after entering the geofence.
It seems like the system prevents the bluetooth scan from starting as long as the display is black.
Once I press the power button (without unlocking or even opening the app) I see the scan results coming in.

I'm already using scan filters since this led to the same problem on all android devices after updating to oreo.

Has anybody experienced the same issue or could point me in the right direction?

Kind regards

Comment: "Once I press the power button" sounds like your app might be in Doze-mode. Maybe check via Android Studio Energy Profiler if there is a "wakelock" active (which you probably need). Even with an active wakelock, your service could be killed, e.g. when there are battery optimizers on the phone. Just a thought, maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! The service is definitely alive. I tried writing a debug message to the log every second. The outcome is: Scan starts - log message every second - no scan result - press power button - sccan results come in.

Comment: I think for others to help you, you need to provide parts of your code. Put some effort into writing the question usually helps to get good help.

Comment: Hi @user2700475, I've exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution ?